# Arduino DDS IOT ESP8266 controlling AD9834

Tags: iot

first post, having probs with uploading sketches on win10, blink sketch loads but when I try either of 2 sketches which have been specifically coded for this duino I get the following error: **redefinition of 'const byte dds_data'**
I have it on good faith that it works on other operating systems. I would also appreciate any advice about how to make a similar one using shields joined together, afaics I just need to join 2 boards readily available on ebay with the 8366 controlling the DDS Ad9834, many thanks in advance, for some reason **the com port is grayed out** in tools menu, https://sites.google.com/site/addsontheinternetofthings/home code below...

```
Arduino: 1.8.5 (Windows 10), Board: "Generic ESP8266 Module, 80 MHz, Flash, nodemcu, 26 MHz, 40MHz, QIO, 512K (no SPIFFS), 2, v2 Lower Memory, Disabled, None, Only Sketch, 115200"

...some code removed so it will fit on this post...

C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\arduino-builder -dump-prefs -logger=machine -hardware C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\hardware -hardware 
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\ESP8266WiFi.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\ESP8266WiFiAP.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\ESP8266WiFiGeneric.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\ESP8266WiFiMulti.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\ESP8266WiFiSTA.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\ESP8266WiFiScan.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClient.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClientSecureAxTLS.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiClientSecureBearSSL.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiServer.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiServerSecureAxTLS.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiServerSecureBearSSL.cpp" -o "nul"
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src\WiFiUdp.cpp" -o "nul"
Generating function prototypes...
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11  -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -w -x c++ -E -CC -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317\sketch\ESP_WiFi_VFO.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\tools-builder\ctags\5.8-arduino11/ctags" -u --language-force=c++ -f - --c++-kinds=svpf --fields=KSTtzns --line-directives "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317\preproc\ctags_target_for_gcc_minus_e.cpp"
Compiling sketch...
"C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\tools\xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc\1.20.0-26-gb404fb9-2/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-g++" -D__ets__ -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/lwip2/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2/tools/sdk/libc/xtensa-lx106-elf/include" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317/core" -c -w  -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536   -DARDUINO=10805 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_GENERIC -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD="ESP8266_GENERIC" -DLED_BUILTIN=2  -DESP8266 "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\cores\esp8266" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\variants\generic" "-IC:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi\src" "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317\sketch\ESP_WiFi_VFO.ino.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Temp\arduino_build_458317\sketch\ESP_WiFi_VFO.ino.cpp.o"
AD9834_Test:20: error: redefinition of 'const byte DDS_data'

 const byte DDS_data = 13;

            ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:25: error: 'const byte DDS_data' previously defined here

 const byte DDS_data=13;

            ^

AD9834_Test:21: error: redefinition of 'const byte DDS_clck'

 const byte DDS_clck = 14;

            ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:26: error: 'const byte DDS_clck' previously defined here

 const byte DDS_clck=14;

            ^

AD9834_Test:22: error: redefinition of 'const byte DDS_fsync'

 const byte DDS_fsync = 16;

            ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:27: error: 'const byte DDS_fsync' previously defined here

 const byte DDS_fsync=16;

            ^

AD9834_Test:26: error: redefinition of 'long unsigned int m'

 unsigned long m;

               ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:30: error: 'long unsigned int m' previously declared here

 unsigned long m;

               ^

AD9834_Test:27: error: redefinition of 'unsigned int m1a'

 unsigned int m1a, m2, m3;

              ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:31: error: 'unsigned int m1a' previously declared here

 unsigned int m1a,m2,m3;

              ^

AD9834_Test:27: error: redefinition of 'unsigned int m2'

 unsigned int m1a, m2, m3;

                   ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:31: error: 'unsigned int m2' previously declared here

 unsigned int m1a,m2,m3;

                  ^

AD9834_Test:27: error: redefinition of 'unsigned int m3'

 unsigned int m1a, m2, m3;

                       ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:31: error: 'unsigned int m3' previously declared here

 unsigned int m1a,m2,m3;

                     ^

AD9834_Test:29: error: redefinition of 'const long unsigned int M_Clk'

 const unsigned long M_Clk = 60000000L;

                     ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:33: error: 'const long unsigned int M_Clk' previously defined here

 const unsigned long M_Clk = 60000000L;

                     ^

AD9834_Test:30: error: redefinition of 'const long unsigned int TwoE28'

 const unsigned long TwoE28 = 268435456L;

                     ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:34: error: 'const long unsigned int TwoE28' previously defined here

 const unsigned long TwoE28 = 268435456L;

                     ^

C:\Users\Ewan\Downloads\ESP_WiFi_VFO\AD9834_Test.ino: In function 'void setup()':

AD9834_Test:36: error: redefinition of 'void setup()'

 void setup() {

      ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:50: error: 'void setup()' previously defined here

 void setup() 

      ^

C:\Users\Ewan\Downloads\ESP_WiFi_VFO\AD9834_Test.ino: In function 'void loop()':

AD9834_Test:42: error: redefinition of 'void loop()'

 void loop() {

      ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:60: error: 'void loop()' previously defined here

 void loop() 

      ^

C:\Users\Ewan\Downloads\ESP_WiFi_VFO\AD9834_Test.ino: In function 'void sendFrequency(double)':

AD9834_Test:49: error: redefinition of 'void sendFrequency(double)'

 void sendFrequency(double frequency) {

      ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:224: error: 'void sendFrequency(double)' previously defined here

 void sendFrequency(double frequency) {

      ^

C:\Users\Ewan\Downloads\ESP_WiFi_VFO\AD9834_Test.ino: In function 'void setFreq(double)':

AD9834_Test:55: error: redefinition of 'void setFreq(double)'

 void setFreq(double(f)) {

      ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:231: error: 'void setFreq(double)' previously defined here

 void setFreq(double(f)){

      ^

C:\Users\Ewan\Downloads\ESP_WiFi_VFO\AD9834_Test.ino: In function 'void setFreqFloat(float)':

AD9834_Test:66: error: redefinition of 'void setFreqFloat(float)'

 void setFreqFloat(float f) {

      ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:242: error: 'void setFreqFloat(float)' previously defined here

 void setFreqFloat(float f){

      ^

C:\Users\Ewan\Downloads\ESP_WiFi_VFO\AD9834_Test.ino: In function 'void writeFreq()':

AD9834_Test:77: error: redefinition of 'void writeFreq()'

 void writeFreq() {

      ^

ESP_WiFi_VFO:253: error: 'void writeFreq()' previously defined here

 void writeFreq(){

      ^

Using library ESP8266WiFi at version 1.0 in folder: C:\Users\Ewan\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp8266\hardware\esp8266\2.4.2\libraries\ESP8266WiFi 
exit status 1
redefinition of 'const byte DDS_data'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two sketches in the project folder ESP_WiFi_VFO.  First is ESP_WiFi_VFO.ino and second is AD9834_Test.ino. Booth sketches have defined same functions, constants and variables so the final program can't be build.

Delete AD9834_Test.ino from the sketch folder ESP_WiFi_VFO (Delete C:\Users\Ewan\Downloads\ESP_WiFi_VFO\AD9834_Test.ino)